# filling empty space of image with conditions bandmath

Tags: python, nan, fill

I'm dealing with sentinel 2 images.
They don't have the same bbox, I'd like to fill the empty space with largest bbox of the series for them to all have the same bbox.

I'd like to do it with bandmath but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.
I could do it with dataframes but I have 800+ images with 2 000 000 000 pixels each and not enough RAM to do it like this.